# Resources on mesh generation for finite element methods

Tags: finite-element, reference-request, mesh-generation

I know that this is not really apart of the rules as this is a recommendation question and these don't really have an answer per say. But, like this forum posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list. To be honest, I am not really sure where else to ask this question.

I would like to start a book guide list on Finite Element and meshing. The thing is, I am not doing this as university research nor as job research. I am interested in this topic and have been for some years. I would like to learn this on my own time. I have been working on building my own simulator for non-linear electromagnetic simulations in 2-D and  I am currently using gmsh as the mesher. I am currently working on integrating gmsh into my source. Progress has been positive. I am able to create a mesh with gmsh where the source code is directly integrated into my project. I would like to modify the current workflow for meshing which means that I need to code to work around GMSH limitations. THis also means, I need to have an understanding of creating a numerical grid for simulations so that I can navigate the source of GMSH and have a better understanding of what is going on.

I am finding that I have a lack on this aspect (numerical grid generation) since the source is referring to alot of terms that I am not familiar with. I apologize if this is breaking any forum rules.

But, I was wondering if anyone can point me to any resources about numerical grid generation? What would be some good references to use for introductory, beginner, intermediate, and advanced? Right now, I feel like I am at beginner. I currently have the resource "Numerical Grid Generation: Foundations and Applications by Joe F. Thompson". Would this resource be good as a starting point?

(I will definitely be going through the deal.II tutorials/manual as the documentation is very detailed. I like that it doesn't quite overload the reader with technical details but explains it with simplicity but to the point)

As a side note, I think that there should be a section for videos. Sometime, those can be helpful.

Comment: Gmsh has recently announced a new API in the works, see http://onelab.info/pipermail/gmsh/2017/011767.html This may make it easy to do what you are talking about here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting a community answer, in line with your model question

## Mesh Generation

[Mesh Generation: Application to Finite Elements](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470611166) (P.-L. George and P. Frey) Hermes, Lyon, 2000. A clear primer on the core technology and terminology of mesh generation. Written in a fairly mathematical style, which might not appeal to those of a more practical outlook. Will fit well with Gmsh, due to the cross-pollination of authors and project.

[Finite Element Mesh Generation](https://www.routledge.com/Finite-Element-Mesh-Generation/Lo/p/book/9781138749245) (Daniel S.H. Lo), CRC, 2015. This book also covers several topics related to mesh generation for finite elements. The style is less mathematical-oriented in comparison with the previous one. The book has code for several algorithms in C++ or Fortran, but they could be better formatted.

[Delaunay Mesh Generation](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejrs/meshbook.html) (Cheng, Dey, Shewchuk), CRC, 2012. Covers some of the really challenging implementation details for Delaunay meshing in 2D and 3D, like exactly how all the edge and face flips work, sliver exudation, etc.

## Geometry and Topology

Edelsbrunner, Herbert. [Geometry and topology for mesh generation](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=v6BybEYVGqYC&lpg=PR11&ots=nurp-0Dfnh&dq=Geometry%20and%20Topology%20for%20Mesh%20Generation&lr&pg=PR11#v=onepage&q&f=false). Vol. 7. Cambridge University Press, 2001. This book concentrates on creation of meshes of triangles and tetrahedra, and the mathematics behind them.

Joseph O'Rourke. [Computational Geometry in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521649765). A book that gives overview of different geometry algorithms such as point in polygon.

Comment: Looking through the Front matter for Mesh Generation, I think that it looks like the book that I am looking for. Although it is $200, I am going to rent it from my library