# References in Scientific Computation for a Computer Science Undergrad?

Tags: reference-request, education

**TLDR:** What references and pre-requisites are necessary for a Computer Science Undergraduate to get ready for a Masters and Career in Scientific Computation / Computational **X**

For a Computer Science Undergraduate, Programming and Mathematics are not a problem but there is definitely a void left in Basic Sciences.

Taking an example of Physics, Computer Science and Engineering Syllabus only contain Basic Courses in Physics - Optics and Material Science.

Keeping that in mind as a Computational Scientist what would you recommend a Computer Science major to start referring to, to cover the lost ground.

References can include :

- Massively Open Online Courses
- Textbooks
- Topics to be covered both in Computing (e.g: HPC) or in Basic Sciences (FEM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at this course here:

https://www.coursera.org/learn/finite-element-method

I took it a few years back and it was a very nice intro into scientific computing.

Also brush up on your PDE skills and Computational Geometry. I started a wiki like answer on this page asking for resources on Meshing:

[Resources on mesh generation for finite element methods](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28388/resources-on-mesh-generation-for-finite-element-methods)

Creating meshes is a core skill to have in scientific computing.

And last but not least, I highly recommend looking into DealII. It has extensive code documentation, video tutorials on programming with DealII for finite element simulations and written tutorials. It is quite literally a treasure trove for this subject.

http://www.dealii.org/8.5.0/index.html

http://www.dealii.org/8.5.0/doxygen/deal.II/Tutorial.html

http://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/videos.html

This should keep you busy for awhile and also prepare you for what is ahead.